# install_name_tool does not make any changes?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sdk, install-name-tool

My app needs to load a dylib provided by a hardware manufacturer. Using otool on the dylib produces this output:

```
$otool -L harwdware.2.dylib 
hardware.2.dylib:
    @executable_path/../Addittional/hardware.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1153.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

And I'd like to change **@executable_path/../Addittional/** to **@executable_path/../Frameworks/** which is actually shorter, so it should fit.
But when I run:

```
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Addittional/hardware.2.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/hardware.2.dylib hardware.2.dylib
```

then nothing happens, nothing changes and the output from otool is the same as before.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `-change` is used to change a reference to a dependent library.  `-id` might be what you want.

Comment: Hey @trojanfoe that worked! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @trojanfoe the correct command line is:

```
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Frameworks/hardware.2.dylib"  hardware.2.dylib
```